# kendo grid row swipe at runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I want to swipe consecutive two rows.Below is my Kendo grid.After 1st click on 1st row's down button it works fine (inter changed first two rows)but next click on 1st row's down button again it does't work as i expected(this stage inter change occurred between 2nd and 3rd row) because i changed seqNo and sorted the grid by seqNo but index remain same.

[image]

### Code

```
 vm.gridOptions =
        {
            dataSource: vm.dataSource,
            sortable: false,
            selectable: true,
            filterable: false,
            scrollable: true,
            pageable: false,
            height: 222,
            columns:
            [
                { title: "...", width: "4%", headerAttributes: { style: "font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" }, attributes: { style: "text-align:center;" }, template: "<span ng-click='vm.downItem(dataItem)' class='btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down' />" },
                { field: "code", title: "Code", width: "10%", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align:center;font-weight: bold;" }, attributes: { style: "text-align:center;" } },
                { field: "name", title: "Name", width: "25%", headerAttributes: { style: "font-weight: bold;" } },
                { field: "reportOrder", title: "Seq No", width: "6%", headerAttributes: { style: "text-align:center;font-weight:bold" }, attributes: { style: "text-align:center;margin:0;padding:1px;" }, template: "<input type='number' class='editable-grid-entry' placeholder='Report Order...' style='text-align:center;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;' ng-model='dataItem.reportOrder'/>" },
            ]
        };

this.downItem = function ( dataItem )
    {
        var index = vm.dataSource.indexOf( dataItem );
        var totalRow = vm.dataSource._data.length;

        var holdSeq = vm.dataSource._data[index + 1].reportOrder;
        vm.dataSource._data[index + 1].reportOrder = dataItem.reportOrder;
        vm.dataSource._data[index].reportOrder = holdSeq;

        vm.dataSource.sort( { field: "reportOrder", dir: "asc" } );
    }
```

Please help me where i should correct or please suggest me a solution to swipe consecutive two rows with Changing seq No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  this.downItem = function ( dataItem )
    {
        var index = vm.dataSource.indexOf( dataItem );
        var downItemValue = dataItem.reportOrder;

        for ( var rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < vm.dataSource._data.length; rowIdx++ )
        {
            if ( vm.dataSource._data[rowIdx].reportOrder == ( dataItem.reportOrder + 1 ) )
            {
                vm.dataSource._data[index].reportOrder = vm.dataSource._data[rowIdx].reportOrder;

                vm.dataSource._data[rowIdx].reportOrder = downItemValue;
                break;
            }

        }

        vm.dataSource.sort( { field: "reportOrder", dir: "asc" } );
    }
```